# Loop through an unordered list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit of a struggle to loop through an unordered list, that is produced by kendo-ui. Looking at its markup, it looks like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group" id="unitlist">
    <li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li id="signalRconveyanceId-P32-HMU-01">
                    <a href="/UnitDetails/Index/1">P32-HMU-01
                        <span class="statusicon" style="background-color: #468847"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="signalRconveyanceId-P32-HMU-02">
                    <a href="/UnitDetails/Index/2">P32-HMU-02
                        <span class="statusicon" style="background-color: #b94a48"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="signalRconveyanceId-XOS-STAGING">
                    <a href="/UnitDetails/Index/3">XOS-STAGING
                        <span class="statusicon" style="background-color: #468847"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="signalRconveyanceId-NWI-100">
                    <a href="/UnitDetails/Index/4">NWI-100
                        <span class="statusicon" style="background-color: #"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
var listItems = $("#unitlist li");
listItems.each(function(li) {
    console.log(li);
});
```

I can get the rows out of the list allright, but all I get out of them is their index number, which in this case is [0, ..., 6].
What I really need is to fetch the id-part `signalRconveyanceId-XXYY` for each list element. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krish/Tjmck/

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution from an answer below :)

Comment: @NicklasWinger: The fundamental point which doesn't seem to be actually explained in the various (otherwise-correct) answers is: The first argument to the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) callback is the index of the element in the jQuery set, not the element. The element is available as `this`, or as the second argument if you prefer.

Comment: Check this if you want to get just the XXYY part of the id http://jsfiddle.net/ZTLd5/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use [jquery attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) like,

```
var listItems = $("#unitlist li");
listItems.each(function(li) {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

**As** your **HTML** shown you should **select list item** like

```
 var listItems = $("#unitlist li ul li");
```

**Updated**

```
var listItems = $("#unitlist li ul li");
listItems.each(function(index,li) {
    console.log(li.id);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HuWZy/3/)

Comment: `$(this).attr("id")` is a ridiculously long and unnecessary way to write `this.id`. Also, accepting the first argument of the `each` callback as `li` is misleading. It *isn't* the `li`, it's the index in the jQuery set. (*Edit:* Not my dv! That seems inappropriate. But it's true that your answer seems to say that the problem is that the OP isn't using `attr`, when in fact the problem is that the OP was using `li`, not `this`. You have to actually look at your code to see the real fix. You might want to correct that.)

Comment: Thanks for this! It works just the way I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `li` is not actually the element - it's the index.  You can refer to each of the `li` elements using `this`...

```
var listItems = $("#unitlist li");
listItems.each(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this:

```
 var listItems = $("#unitlist li");
   listItems.each(function(li) {
   $id = $(this).attr('id');
   console.log($id);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/cTEHY/